# Adding balance calculation mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to calculate the balance from 3 different values:

**status:** is either equal to correct or wrong

**odds:** for instance 1.70

**stake:** 100 fixed

```
status  | odds    |
wrong   |  1.70   |
correct |  3.00   |
```

What i want:

```
status  | odds    | balance
wrong   |  1.70   | -100
correct |  3.00   | 200
```

So basically

```
If status = 'wrong'
balance = balance - 100
else
balance = balance + odds * 100
```

Mysql:

```
SELECT status, odds FROM betting
```

How can i implement balance?

Comment: You just asked the same question and deleted it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the betting balance in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407086/calculating-the-betting-balance-in-mysql)

Comment: The result seems dependent upon the 'order' of the rows, but how do you establish row order?

Comment: strawberry just by id.

Comment: In that case, amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are one way of doing this kind of thing...

```
SELECT status
     , odds
     , CASE WHEN status = 'wrong' 
            THEN @balance := @balance - 100 
            ELSE @balance := @balance + (odds * 100) END balance 
  FROM my_table
     , (SELECT @balance:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
```